# How to pass the system environment variable to nginx.conf

Tags: nginx, env

My question is how to pass the system environment variable to nginx.conf?

I define a system variable CLASSPATH in /etc/profile:

**export CLASSPATH=$CLASSPATH:`$HADOOP_HOME/bin/hadoop classpath --glob`**

And I define tow variables in nginx.conf:

**env TEST_ENV=/usr/local/test;**

**env $CLASSPATH;**

and print the variables by lua:

location /lua {

```
default_type text/html;

content_by_lua '

    ngx.say(os.getenv("TEST_ENV"));

    ngx.say(os.getenv("CLASSPATH"));

';
```

}

The results as below:

**ngx.say(os.getenv("TEST_ENV")); ====> /usr/local/test**

**ngx.say(os.getenv("CLASSPATH")); ====> nil**

Looks the env directive can't pass the system value to nginx.conf

Any suggestion?

Comment: Try `env CLASSPATH;` without the `$`.

Comment: env CLASSPATH; print nil too.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I do it using fastcgi and hopefully it'll be useful to you or anyone out there. My env variables are defined under /etc/environment. Note that after you define them you can use `source /etc/environment` to make them available to your session.

Let's take for example one of your variables. 
This would go under /etc/environment
`CLASSPATH=$HADOOP_HOME/bin/hadoop classpath`

Once these have been defined in the system, for nginx I'd add the following within the location block:
`fastcgi_param CLASSPATH $CLASSPATH;
include fastcgi_params;`